# Is it possible to use a an SQL query to find out whether a Mirth channel is disabled or not?

Tags: sql, mirth

Is it possible to use a an SQL query to find out whether a Mirth channel is disabled or not?  I know it can be done via API calls but I am trying to use a purely database method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

`SELECT * FROM public.configuration where name = 'channelMetadata';` will return an XML string which contains the channel metadata with the enabled/disabled state, last modification timestamp, and pruning options.

These entries look like:

```
  <entry>
    <string>C88749A7-BDF5-45D8-AC41-DF0884B15098</string>
    <com.mirth.connect.model.ChannelMetadata>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
      <lastModified>
        <time>1621527614990</time>
        <timezone>America/Chicago</timezone>
      </lastModified>
      <pruningSettings>
        <pruneMetaDataDays>3</pruneMetaDataDays>
        <archiveEnabled>false</archiveEnabled>
      </pruningSettings>
    </com.mirth.connect.model.ChannelMetadata>
  </entry>
```

They are a serialized Java `Map<String, com.mirth.connect.model.ChannelMetadata>`. The key is the channel ID, you can look that up in the `channel` table to find name, the channel definition itself, etc.

Note that this shows enabled/disabled which **is not** the same as started/stopped. The started/stopped state is only available via API calls since its the running state of MC and kept in memory.

Comment: Thank you!  I know we could use the API but in this case getting the data directly works for us.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, provided the database you are using for Mirth's persistence has the ability to use **xpath** in the query.

For example, here is a query for Postgresql that lists the channel id and name along with that channel's 'enabled' value:

```
select c.id, c.name, cfg.enabled
from (select cfg.cid, cfg.enabled
      from (select value from configuration where name='channelMetadata') as x, LATERAL (
          SELECT
              (xpath('./string/text()', cvalue.node::xml))[1]::text AS cid,
              (xpath('./*/enabled/text()', cvalue.node::xml))[1]::text AS enabled
          FROM
              unnest(CAST(xpath('/map/entry', value::xml) as text)::text[]) as cvalue(node)
          ) as cfg) as cfg, channel c
where cfg.cid=c.id
order by 2;
```